# Facebook App Permission Getting Toggled Somehow

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios6

I have Facebook's SSO working properly in my iPhone app and most of my users have not been experiencing any issues. However, a small number of them have been reporting errors with Facebook Connect and not being able to create an account. After an email exchange with one, we determined that the app permission toggle under Settings->Facebook was somehow set to disallow my app from using Facebook.

I have since added an error message telling the user this might be the case but my question is how did this switch get toggled in the first place? It would seem that a user would have to manually toggle this switch, right? I also looked for an API method that might do this e.g. rejecting Facebook SSO the first time a user saw the dialog asking for permission; I could not find any such code.

Any ideas? I'm hoping this problem will solve itself with the error dialog I've put in but if possible, I'd like to remove this issue altogether.

Comment: Are you sure the user didn't select 'no' to a popup asking if your app could access their Facebook data?

Comment: They did. However, when I do this on my test device, I'm not seeing the switch being toggled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, using the native dialog with iOS6 and rejecting the permissions request (the first one, at least, not sure about requests which are asking an existing user for more permissions) will toggle that switch

If you need to debug, try uninstalling the app from your facebook profile (a `HTTP DELETE request to /<USER ID>/permissions` will do this, or you can do it in the facebook app settings), remove the iOS app, then install it and try to connect for 'the first time' again

Comment: Ok, I suspected this to be the case but I can't get a repro even with deleting the app from FB, etc. Guess I'll release it into the wild and see how it goes. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Looking at my own phone, there's one app with that toggle set to no, and i definitely rejected it when they asked - i know that's an anecdote and not a repro, but it's something :)