# Toggle integrated Facebook app permissions

Tags: ios, facebook

Is there any way to programatically remove app permission while using integrated iOS login?

I've tried DELETEing various (or all) `/me/permissions` before closing the session, but the OS will happily give me a new one without prompts when I ask for the removed permissions back.
This session then doesn't work, as Facebook still things those permissions were revoked.

Is there a way to revoke permissions such that you get correctly prompted when logging in again, without the user having to work out they need to go to Settings and cycle some things?

Related:

- [Facebook API SDK revoke access](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9050190/476716)
- [Facebook App Permission Getting Toggled Somehow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14488325/476716)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After revoking the permissions, call `[FBSession renewSystemCredentials:]` or `[ACAccountStore renewCredentialsForAccount:completion]` to update the OS's cache.

This solves the problem when you delete some of the permissions, but not when you delete all of them (which still returns FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled even if they press "Allow").

Comment: How could we revoke the permission please ?

Comment: @AhdRadwan that's in the question.

Comment: I see , by using this request 
DELETE /{user-id}/permissions/{permission-name}  we can revoke it 
but my question is how could we use this request